# AAD B2C - User consent not asked

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, scopes

Context:

- Azure AD B2C for a Tenant
- External Identity Provider configured
- B2C login flow (sign-in sign-up) configured
- API backend defined as Application with 2 scopes in AAD B2C of this Tenant

  - "Admins and users" can consent
- External client/Third Party app (confidential) defined as Application in AAD B2C of this Tenant
- External client/Third Party app has permissions on the 2 scopes

  - Status is "nothing", I did not grant admin consent, I want the users to give consent themselves
- In Enterprise applications | User settings

  - Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf: YES
- In Consent and permissions | User consent settings
  => Allow user consent for apps - All users can consent for any app to access the organization's data.

Authorize URL:

```
https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?p=B2C_1_signup_login
&client_id=xxx
&nonce=defaultNonce
&redirect_uri=xxx
&scope=offline_access%20openid%20profile%20email%20https%3A%2F%xxx.onmicrosoft.com%2F6D6E9DF9-4546-47D8-8EDB-D65EC89A0E90%2Fproduct_scope_2
&response_type=code
&code_challenge=ThisIsntRandomButItNeedsToBe43CharactersLong
&code_challenge_method=plain
```

User is redirected to external IDP provider, logs in. User is not asked for consent. Callback url is called with a `code`, which can be exchanged for an `id_token`. Audience (`aud`) is the `client_id` of the Client Application, not the API.

If I grant admin consent, the `code` can be exchanged for an `access_token` and `id_token`, and the audience is OK (API's `client_id`).

What must I configure to have the users asked to give consent, for the Client Application + the scopes? I haven't been able to find any article about this: user consent AND external identity provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do an Admin Consent in AAD B2C. It does not have an OAuth2.0 consent prompt for users. Instead it’s modelled with a terms of use. You never do an Oauth consent unless you share your data with a third party.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/terms-of-service

> In Consent and permissions | User consent settings => Allow user consent for apps - All users can consent for any app to access the organization's data.

Irrelevant to AAD B2C apps.

If you still want some consent UX:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/service-consent

Comment: Thanks JasSuri for your answer. Just: `Irrelevant to AAD B2C apps` means Third Party apps (external client in initial description) shouldn't be managed this way, or irrelevant because it's modelled with TOS and the solution is to implement some UX (policy with the Trust Framework)?

Comment: Irrelevant because it simply doesn’t apply to B2C App Registrations, users share the data with you, it’s first party. Think about any website/app you’ve signed up for. oauth consent is modelled when you ask a user to share data from a service (that isn’t owned by you) to your app. EG sign in via google to your B2C app will trigger a consent at google. Whether it’s useful or applicable in your consumer facing apps is not really covered by any standard I’m aware of. And yes, you can model that UX with the Identity Experience Framework if you like.

Comment: Ok so in the context I've described (POC only), the Third Party are not "owned" by me, but registered as B2C Apps to benefits from AAD OAuth2 server capabilities (+ you can plug external identity provider). Which feels to me as edge case or hack when I'm reading your comments. Thanks Jas.